# C++ virtual method not called as desired

Tags: c++

I'm stuck and already tried a alot to solve this "virtual" problem and so I beg you to help me, cause it's probably something stupid that a "trained eye" can solve in seconds..

The problem: When I do the following in main:

```
PrologConnector swiProlog;
swiProlog = PrologConnector::connectorFactory(PrologConnector::swi,argv);
swiProlog.send("blabla");
```

always the send method of the PrologConnector class is called, but not the one from the subclass..
Do you see the problem?

Thanks for the help!!

Here's the code:
PrologConnector.h

```
class PrologConnector {
   virtual int send(char * cmd);
   virtual int init(char **argv);
   static PrologConnector connectorFactory(Prolog prolog, char ** argv);
};
```

PrologConnector.cpp

```
int PrologConnector::send(char * argv) {
  std::cout << "not wanted"<<std::endl;
  return 0;
}


int PrologConnector::init(char **argv) {
  //TODO add implementation
  return 0;
}


PrologConnector PrologConnector::connectorFactory(Prolog prolog, char **argv) {
  if (prolog == swi) {
    SWIConnector sc;
    sc.init(argv);
    return sc;
  }

std::cout <<"Error in initialization!"<<std::endl;
PrologConnector pc;
return pc;
}
```

SWIConnector.h:

```
class SWIConnector : public PrologConnector {
  int send(char *cmd);
  int init(char **argv);
};
```

SWIConnector.cpp:

```
int SWIConnector::init(char **argv) {
//some action going on
}


int SWIConnector::send(char * cmd) {

//some action going on
}
```

Comment: You can only call overridden functions via the base class if you create a pointer to the base class' object and initialize it with an instance of a derived class.

Comment: [What is the slicing problem in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have here is *[object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c)*. In order to use objects polymorphically, you *have* to access them through a pointer or a reference.

The signature of your factory method should be changed to return a `PrologConnector*` or `PrologConnector&`, after which you will be able to see the expected behavior.

Comment: Yes-- connector factory should return a reference to the created object, which should be allocated on the heap.

Comment: @PreetSangha: I 'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: The *usually* and *more rarely* in the answer are purely speculative. While polymorphic storage of objects is done through pointers, **access** is often done through references.

Comment: @jon - no problem. I wanted to understand where the copy of was happening as opposed to the assignment (as the OP expected). With references or pointers it's easy to comprehend.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is common and is called "slicing". You're assigning a derived class to an instance of the base class, and all attributes of the derived class are being lost during the copy.

Use a pointer or reference to the class instead.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what happens in this method:

```
PrologConnector PrologConnector::connectorFactory(Prolog prolog, char **argv) {
  if (prolog == swi) {
    SWIConnector sc;
    sc.init(argv);
    // return sc;
    return PrologConnector(sc);
  }
```

as you return variable of the type PrologConnector. And PrologConnector's methods will be called.

You need to return pointers rather than copy of objects.

Comment: Are they not Stack objects too?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, that was exactly what happened.. Never heard about that before :)

Another hint:

```
PrologConnector* PrologConnector::connectorFactory(Prolog prolog, char **argv) {
  if (prolog == swi) {
  SWIConnector *sc = new SWIConnector;
  sc->init(argv);
  return sc;
}
```

I had to use "new" to instantiate that SWIConnector, otherwise I get a "segmentation fault" in the main function. I am not completely sure why, because I thought the "SWIConnector x" already allocates memory, but there seems to be another reason :)

Regards