# Move assignment operator in subclass not being called / inherited

Tags: c++, c++11

I've got a simple base class and two classes that inherit from it.  The problem is that the move assignment operators in each of the child classes aren't being used.  Here's basically what I have:

```
class Parent {
public:
    virtual ~Parent();
    virtual Parent& operator=(Parent &&parent);
};

class Child1 : public Parent {
public:
    ~Child1();
    Child1& operator=(Child1 &&child);
};

class Child2 : public Parent {
public:
    ~Child2();
    Child2& operator=(Child2 &&child);
};
```

The implementations are littered with logs, so I know what's being called and when.  Then, I run this (pseudo)code:

```
Parent &p {};
if (x == 1)
    p = Child1 {};
else
    p = Child2 {};
```

And I get output that looks something like this:

```
: Child constructor
: Parent move operator
: Child destruct
: SIGSEGV
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're trying to turn a double decker bus into a bus

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ virtual method not called as desired](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734077/c-virtual-method-not-called-as-desired)

Comment: And see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing?lq=1

Comment: `Parent &p {};` should not compile, you cannot assign temporary to lvalue reference

Answer (score 3):

This is a classic case of [slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) where you are assigning an instance of a derived type to an instance of a base type.  To fix this you have to use dynamic allocation and pointers:

```
std::unique_ptr<Parent> p;

if(x == 1)
  p = std::make_unique<Child1>();
else
  p = std::make_unique<Child2>();
```

Comment: Thanks - still learning about this.  Unfortunately, std::make_unique isn't available for me.  (I'm compiling with Xcode for cross-platform support: MacOSX, iOS, Android via JNI, etc.)  Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with all of those platforms.  If they don't have C++11 then they probably also don't have Boost, so raw new/delete might be the only option.  That or you could roll your own smart pointer to handle memory management.

Comment: @cetcet yes `p.reset( new Child1 );`

Comment: @ChrisHayden `std::make_unique` is not available in c++11, only in c++14

Comment: @Slava You're right!  Hopefully @cetcet has C++11 and he can still use `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Yes, C++11.  Also I'm stubborn and used to Objective C where the sort of shenanigan I'm trying to do here is commonplace. ;)

Answer (score 2):

C++ doesn't work that way. You can't just assign a subclass object to a base class object and expect that to work; this mistake is known as "object slicing".

Also, your if-statement's condition is not comparison, it's assignment.

Comment: The if statement was a typo (here, not in my code); it has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You have overloaded `operator=` for the following cases: (pseudocode)

```
Parent = Parent&&
Child1 = Child1&&
Child2 = Child2&&
```

However your code then attempts to do `Parent = Child1`, which wasn't one of those options.  Note that the left-hand-side is *the class type in which the function is defined*  - the return value type does not affect function overloading.

There is never implicit conversion from base class to derived class in C++, as that would be too dangerous. (You must use a cast to request that behaviour).  For example, in this case it would be wrong to pass a `Parent` as argument to a function expecting a `Child1` because that Parent is not a Child1.

However, there is implicit conversion from derived class to base class reference. So `Parent = Child1` will match `Parent = Parent&&`. It cannot match any of the others because the left-hand-side is not implicitly converted to a derived class.

To solve this problem, your choices include:

- Explicitly define `Parent = Child1&&` and `Parent = Child2&&` inside `Parent` (this will need forward declarations)
- Have `Parent = Parent&&` use tag-dispatching or `dynamic_cast` or otherwise, to achieve the desired behaviour for all of the child classes

As mentioned by others, perhaps your design needs a re-think, as you are slicing on purpose here, but it is rare that slicing is an intended part of an object-oriented design. Possibly you intended `Parent p;` to actually be a reference or pointer to Parent, instead of an actual Parent.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I don't want to convert anything.  I suppose my mistake was not using references and/or pointers.